# Erro na código errado no setType " non-static method setType(String) "

Tags: java, android

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="Invite"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    ads:fabSize="mini"
    ads:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" 


    public void Invite(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Intent.setType("text/plain");
        Intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "COMPARTILHAR MEU APP");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

> Error:(199, 15) error: non-static method putExtra(String,String)
>   cannot be referenced from a static context
>
> Error:(198, 15) error: non-static method setType(String) cannot be
>   referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui:

```
Intent.setType("text/plain");
Intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "COMPARTILHAR MEU APP");
```

Ao usar **I**ntent (o nome da classe) e não **i**ntent (o nome da variável que você criou), você está tentando acessar estaticamente métodos não estáticos, daí o erro.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "COMPARTILHAR MEU APP");
```